# Leer código de verificación de un sms desde IOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3, app

Quiero hacer una pequeña app para registrar usuarios.
Una vez que se registre el usuario se le enviará un sms con un código de verificación.

¿Solo necesito saber si es posible acceder a la lista de sms y obtener el código sin que el usuario se mueva de la aplicación?

El lenguaje que utilizo es `swift`

Se que en `Android` se puede, pero `IOS` es distinto pone muchas pegas al obtener información del usuario, por eso mi pregunta

Comment: @lois6b Preguntar sobre cómo detectar la recepción de un sms me parece una pregunta bastante concreta... y este tipo de preguntas no son las típicas que se hacen cuando alguien intenta que le hagan los deberes. A mi me parece una pregunta válida.

Comment: @eferion ya no se que pensar. lo que yo entiendo como pregunta valida es "en este codigo para detectar un sms me falla la comunicacion con la app y blablalba .."  pero esto es muy amplio. Pero para eso somos comunidad, para votar ...  si la mayoria está de acuerdo por mi estupendo

Comment: @lois6b Lo se, solo expongo mi punto de vista particular. Generalmente (recordemos que cada caso es diferente) yo no estoy en contra de las preguntas que traten temas complejos (como pueda ser este) sin aportar código ya que si alguien tiene una solución y la publica nos podemos beneficiar todos. En la sección inglesa te puedes encontrar preguntas de esta índole y ves que tienen respuestas ingeniosas o elegantes... no todo debería ser responder a cuestiones de tipo "_la consola no me imprime el valor que debería_"

Comment: @MiquelColl me puedes explicar porque esta pregunta es demasiado amplia??

Comment: `Existen muchas respuestas posibles, o las buenas respuestas son demasiado extensas para este formato. Añade detalles para reducir el conjunto de respuestas o separar un problema que se puede responder en pocos párrafos.` Independientemente de si *sólo* necesitas saber si sí o si no (Otras aplicaciones YA lo hacen) mirando la descripción a mi me queda claro, no? Y en cualquier caso la comunidad puede abrir o cerrar, faltaría más. Des de mi punto de vista está claro pero este no es el sitio de discusión, si quieres puedes publicar una pregunta en meta o hablarlo en el chat.

Comment: Aunque se abra y a mi me parezca interesante lo cierto es que si no acota un poco más la pregunta dudo que nadie la responda.

Comment: @eferion si seguro que alguien la responde. pero la cosa es que tiene que editarla si o si. no puede ser que se cierre, no edite nada (más que el titulo raro ese que puso) y se reabra. tiene que editarla para que se centre en algo, sea mas conciso

Comment: @lois6b no te lo discuto. Esa maniobra para forzar su apertura no es la habitual

Comment: Evita colocar cosas en el título como "[En proceso de reapertura]". No se sabe si será re abierta o no.

Comment: @eferion y demás personas. Cuando sucedan estos casos, lo mejor es crear una pregunta en [meta] respecto a la pregunta sobre si debería ser re abierta. Allí tendrá más atención a diferencia de los comentarios que puede recibir aquí y nos beneficiamos más como comunidad.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ok Tomo nota

Answer (score 0):

1.- Si haces que el mensaje pueda visualizarse en el centro de notificaciones de ios, cuando el usuario lo reciba y lo vea allí, le bastaría con deslizar hacia abajo el centro de notificaciones y así no saldría de la app. Pues aunque es algo externo, no obliga a salir de la app. No es una respuesta a tu pregunta pero es una solución posible.

2.- Otro tema sería que al registrarse reciba el código en su area de usuario. (Dentro de la app)

3.- También puedes hacer que el código sea una combinación de 3 cifras/letras de manera que sea tan fácil de recordar de que cuando aparece en pantalla el código tan solo tenga que ponerlo sin salirse.
En esta opción puedes ponerle al usuario de la app algo del estilo:

> "Si tienes habilitadas las notificaciones de ios en pantalla
>   bloqueada" Espera 5 segundos y verás el código aparecer en pantalla.